# how to set alpha for linearLayout on Service class

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a service class which contains a `WindowManager` in it.The `WindowManager` contains a simple `LinearLayout` in it.The `LinearLayout` is empty and transparent.I am trying to set an alpha value for that layout like this:

```
leftSwipe.getBackground().setAlpha(100)    //leftSwipe is a LinearLayout
```

But I am getting error like this:

```
Unable to create service com.example.adarsh.test.Window: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)' on a null object reference
```

Why is it giving me `NullPointerException` even  my `LinearLayout` is present in the `WindowManager`.I have used `LinearLayout` like this:

```
LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftS=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    l.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
    l.setLayoutParams(leftS);

    listWindow.addView(l, myParams);    //listWindow is my WindowManager
```

Answer (score 1):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method *'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.**setAlpha(int)**'* on a null object reference

already tells you most of what happens. `l.getBackground()` returns a `Drawable` instance or null. In your case it was null, so that the `NullPointerException` was thrown.

Make sure to have a background set or try to implement a different solution to your problem.